# Question in limbo between History SE and Philosophy SE?

Tags: support

This post:

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/37469/has-anyone-argued-that-what-caused-the-problems-in-the-ussr-would-have-been-simi

was deemed to be more about history than about philosophy by some contributors. I disagree, it can be analyzed from a Marxists perspective or from a philosophy of history perspective. The OP accepted my answer but then it got migrated anyway to the history SE. Then the History mods rejected the migration and now it is locked and stuck in limbo, not allowing any further discussion.

Can someone bring back to the Philosophy SE?

Comment: hm, sorry about that. i've also lost question privleges -- at least!

Comment: @user3293056 don't think it's your fault. The boneheadedness of the History SE mods seems to be the main issue. They shut down the question off the bat. That never happens here - there's always a period where the post can be debated or modified.